# App users to 'invite' their friends, not request something from friends

Tags: facebook, invite

I'm trying to find a way for users, while inside my app, to invite their facebook friends to use my App. Sounds pretty simple right? I keep finding information online on these 'Requests' but they're not requesting anything from their friends, they're simply inviting them to, or suggesting to use my app. When I tried a code snippet that I found on the developer site, it looked as though it is more intended for a user to request an in-game item from another game player who is a friend. There was a generic message saying something about so and so is requesting something from you in [app name] or something like that. Shouldn't there be a simpler way for friends to invite friends to my app while within my App? Thanks -Chris